# Duration in milliseconds is very high for a batch job and recorded in debug log. What could be the reason for the huge duration?

Tags: debug

After One of the batch job ran, i got the log details as follows that shows huge duration in milliseconds. Where could this time consumed? What it means actually? I am worrying that i could have hit any governor limits.

**Apex Debug Log Detail**

User    Kirk Cizerle
Date    8/13/2014 6:05:00 AM PDT
Status  Success
Application Unknown
Request Type    Application
Operation   Job2
**Duration (ms) 2,147,483,647**
Log Size (bytes)    1,557
Log

```
29.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
06:05:00.029 (29627884)|EXECUTION_STARTED
06:05:00.029 (29667015)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p90000005ARtn|Job2
06:05:00.051 (51296166)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p90000005ARtn|ScheduleBatchCreateFeedItems.ScheduleBatchCreateFeedItems()
06:05:00.051 (51315789)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|ScheduleBatchCreateFeedItems
06:05:00.051 (51439758)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p90000005ARE9|BatchCreateFeedItems.BatchCreateFeedItems()
06:05:00.051 (51450212)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|BatchCreateFeedItems
06:05:00.051 (51486791)|CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[4]|01p90000005ARE9|<init>(String)
06:05:00.051 (51593530)|CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[4]|01p90000005ARE9|<init>(String)
06:05:00.051 (51623554)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|Database.executeBatch(APEX_OBJECT)
06:05:00.089 (89866093)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[5]|Database.executeBatch(APEX_OBJECT)
06:05:00.744 (91199573)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
06:05:00.744|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 10
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 10
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

06:05:00.744|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

06:05:00.091 (91227439)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Job2
06:05:00.092 (92767534)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: Holy 24.86 days batman! Is it even possible for a batch to run that long? I would say something is aloof and you may need to log a case.

Comment: This appears to be a bug that occurs if you `System.abortJob` on a scheduled class while it's executing (e.g. you abort the current scheduled job within the execute method). We see this all the time in our logs. I think that they're using a 32-bit signed integer for that field, and trying to assign the value -1, which they apparently then use Math.abs... resulting in abs((-2^31)+1).

Answer (score -1):

Time duration which is showing on the above displayed in the debug log includes the time from the creation of the log, which created early after the apex context is created, but potentially before apex class loading, which has to happen before we start executing any apex. Also the
end time is recorded after the file is written.

You can go through below link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000941iIAA